# Can two processes on same machine connect to the same port?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, port

I have a few basic questions about sockets programming. I am trying to write a program (in C, linux) in which several client processes connect to a server process and also the clients need to connect to themselves. Though the clients would reside on separate machines, them being on the same machine is also a case. These are my questions.

1. Can two client processes communicate with each other on the separate port? In that case none of them listens to a port (like how the server does). They just connect to a port using a socket and talk to each other. Is that possible?
2. If not, how can I make communication between the clients?

Any idea on this would be of help. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulR, I don't have an opinion on it, I just posted a link which I thought might be of your interest.

Comment: Thanks Paul R. I'm quite new to the forum and I'm not much familiar with the rules here.. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **no**, in TCP this is not possible. When establishing the connection in TCP, you are always connecting to listening port, so one of the clients **must** listen.
2. one of the clients needs to open listening port, but which one? **Use the server as an arbiter**! Employ a protocol where server moderates:

   - server decides which client will open the port
   - that client opens the port, listens to it and sends its address (host:port) to the server
   - servers sends it to the other client
   - the other client can connect now!

And if you were asking if two processes can listen on the same port on the same machine, then the answer is no. But using the above protocol you can avoid this situation.

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thank you. I was just wondering if there's a way to make the connections between the clients independent of the server... Come to think of it, now it sounds a bit odd...

Answer (score 1):

A socket connection always needs a connecting and a listening side - one side needs to listen. Have one client process create a listening port and the other connect to this port.

Comment: It's actually possible for two clients to connect to one another, if both are connecting simultaneously, see [RFC793](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt), page 30 on Simultaneous initiation

Comment: but there is no API to achieve this reliable. This would be cool to connect two nodes behind NAT.

Comment: It works reliably enough if both sides know the other's ports and `connect()` to each other at roughly the same time. This would probably require some mediator, though, and might annoy systems that do NAT somewhat.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you want to make clients to communicate each other, make use of a server which listens on a port and directs to the other client nothing but to direct to right clients.
2. If you dont want to use a server, then in you client application u have to make one port for listening and another port for spitting data. So it will be only one-one talking.

If I'm correct for the answer you are looking for: Yes, two processes on same machine can connecto to same port. It is nothing but two different entities trying to connect to a server.